# "Post Locked" vs. "Post Closed"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, community

What is the difference between "Post Locked" and "Post Closed" ?

Comment: FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq

Comment: Thanks. I had actually found the answer to "closed" on the faq after asking the question. Why on earth is the answers spilt between SO & meta? :S

Comment: Looks like they're still migrating questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

closed: no new answers can be added to a question.

locked: the post cannot be manipulated or interacted with in any way by anyone other than a moderator.

UPDATE -- to make this easier to understand, we modified lock so that when you lock a question, it also prevents new answers from being added. Locking answers behaves the same as before.