# Meta posts about specific users?

Tags: discussion

It seems we are not allowed now to question moderators. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42754/why-was-this-meta-question-closed-as-a-duplicate

And yes Jeff, I fully expect to be put in the sin bin for this, and maybe on SO too. Some of us believe in open expression in both code, documentation, use and support, and believe that suppressing this in any form is wrong. You seem to disagree. OK, but consider that the people like me providing free and open answerers on your site is what makes it work.

Comment: This should be very entertaining...

Comment: Looks like you are not in good mood today, +1

Comment: Just wait for them to think up a new policy that targets you specifically but fluffs in other users to make it seem not so direct.

Answer (score 15):

When have we ever allowed attacking other users? Whether it's a moderator or not is irrelevant; if someone started a thread titled "I think Neil Butterworth is a terrible user!" I would edit it in the exact same way.

Concentrate on the specific posts you have issues with. "Why was this question closed?" is a totally reasonable meta question. "Why does {user x} suck so much?" is not.

Comment: +1 for **I would edit it in the exact same way.**

Comment: I knew this was going to be entertaining...

Comment: Having just read through all the links in this 'saga' I have come to a conclusion - some people take this thing WAY to seriously. It's just a few votes, and besides - criticizing users is not the way to win people to your side. (I'm of course referring to Neil)

Comment: Also, you're definitely allowed to questions us.  The moderator you're complaining about explicitly requested that you do. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39405/moderator-accountability-request

Comment: Questioning is good. Criticizing people - not so good. Insulting, well that's just plain bad.

Comment: @Bill Which I've already pointed out .. several times during the saga: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42754/why-was-this-meta-question-closed-as-a-duplicate/42755#42755

Answer (score 5):

If you want to question a moderator, email them. Most of them have contact information somewhere.

If you want to complain about the actions of a moderator, email team@stackoverflow.com. Jeff loves email.

And if you want others to commiserate with you on Meta, be subtle... For some reason, folks are much more likely to agree when you don't actually name names.

Comment: lol @ Jeff loves email

Comment: Sorry, doesn't "locked" mean you can't add to the question/answers? Apparently not. So what does it mean?

Comment: @Neil, Only 'closed' prevents additional answers.

Comment: @Chacha: that used to be the case, but it changed because apparently that confused people - now locking *also* prevents new answers... @Neil: ...however, there's a hefty grace period that lets you cram in answers after locking (and actually, I suspect there might be another bug involved here... edge cases like this tend to get ignored)

Comment: @Chacha: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13059/post-locked-vs-post-closed/13060#13060 I guess 10k's can still add answers. Edit: or maybe Shog was in the process of typing just after the lock.

Comment: Oh arse. I think Jeff's meaning was obvious, whatever the technicalities - discussion over.

Comment: the meaning of locked was recently changed to *also* mean no new answers can be added. Sorry for the confusion; it probably always should have behaved that way.

Comment: @Jeff So I don't get to make a reply as an answer? Why am I not surprised?

Comment: I tried to post a comment for the question but there was no grace period...