# Why was "What's your favorite programmer cartoon" protected?

Tags: support, specific-question, moderator-abilities, locked, protected-questions

[What’s your favorite “programmer” cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon)

> locked by Community♦ **Aug 6 '09** at 16:23

> protected by Marc Gravell♦ **Jul 5 '10** at 19:33
>   This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have more than 10 reputation.

Since you cannot reply to locked posts what's the point of protecting it?

Comment: **Historical note #1:** The question was locked automatically as part of the migration to Meta. This migration was... [ill-advised, and quickly reversed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13047/favorite-programming-cartoon-question-is-not-meta).
**Historical note #2:** At the time it was originally locked, locking did *not* prevent new answers from being added. [Locking for questions was later extended to include this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13059/post-locked-vs-post-closed/13060#13060)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was [reopened Feb 8th](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/84556/revisions) ( and the lock notice is only part of its history? ), since

[**from the blog**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/):

> While we used to lock these kinds of questions, that’s not really what a lock was intended for. Locking a question is a bit of a nuclear option in this scenario, as locking prevents the question from getting votes, comments, or edits when the question itself wasn’t even the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that was the first question they protected on StackOverflow. Maybe it was a test?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/84556/revisions), the lock was part of a successful vote to migrate to Meta.

Without getting an answer from Marc, it's tough to say why the question is still locked given that the desired result should be protected status.

I strongly suspect the lock just went unnoticed. The [mod menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58989/display-conflict-between-a-questions-mod-menu-and-a-new-answers-edit-bar) contains both "lock" and "unlock" items, and the "locked by Community" text was probably obscured off the bottom of the viewing area.