# Migrating questions causes too much visual noise

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

When you vote for a question to be moved to another site, the question is closed not with one, not with two, but with *three* grey boxes, all with a lot of links, all linking to different stuff. That is just too much visual noise:

[image: Whoa, MSPaint really compresses this heavily]

To add insult to injury, there are two links to stackoverflow.com, but they link to different URLs: The top one links to the new question, the bottom one links to the main page.

My suggestion:

- Remove the "Locked by Community" box - for migrated questions, this is unneccessary information.
- Either remove the third box or change the link to the target site to link to the question
- Ideally, combine the third and first box so that you only have one grey box in total: "migrated to stackoverflow.com by User1, User2, User3, User4, User5 2 days ago"

**Edit:** Here is how I think it makes most sense:

[image: PNG, for great justice!]

Comment: Try PNG next time, it compresses okay in Paint compared to JPEG.

Comment: If the number of colors are low, use PNG.

Comment: Yeah, I'll either do that or use Paint.net in the future. In the meantime, just imagine that the high compression is fully intentional in order to emphasize the visual noise :P

Comment: COME ON STUM! This is images 101, man!! :) http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000464.html

Comment: MS Paint can do PNG fairly well. Your screenshot is more a reminder of getting some visine.

Comment: It wouldn't look as bad if not for the default text colour on SU...

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11580

Comment: How are you compressing these screenshots?

Comment: Get the http://www.screengrab.org plugin for firefox in the future.  it makes making screenshots of webpages far too easy.

Comment: Requires Firefox though, which I don't use since they broke it in 3.0.

Answer (score 7):

Agree. I would even go so far as to say that the migrated announcement is the only one necessary, so long as all three (close/lock/migrate) are present in the revision list.

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with [Kyle's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16740/migrating-questions-causes-too-much-visual-noise/16741#16741) in one aspect: The close vote information should still be visible after the migration. My proposal: having one notice saying

**Migrated to *stackoverflow.com* by *UserA, UserB, UserC* 2 days ago**

Comment: That's what I support, it's the cleanest way to have all relevant information without duplication and without it being too confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. My suggestion is to put the names of the migraters in the revision list, which will still be available any time after migration.

Comment: But you need to look up the revision list in order to see it, I think it should be visible on the question's main page. A user who is new to the site will probably not know how look up the revisions (and new users are the ones most likely to ask questions that belong on one of the other sites).