# Make the destination link to a migrated questions more obvious?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Migrating questions causes too much visual noise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16740/migrating-questions-causes-too-much-visual-noise)
>   [“Nicer” migration notice when closing questions as “belongs on X”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11580/nicer-migration-notice-when-closing-questions-as-belongs-on-x)

When a question is migrated, there are 8 links:

- "migrated to {destination site}", where {destination site} is the link to the new question
- "locked by {community}", where community is a link to the community user
- "closed as belongs on {destination site} by {user1}, ... , {user5} {some time} ago" where {destination site} now goes to the site's home page, and user{n} are the user-profiles

Problems:

- it isn't very friendly; a lot of migrated questions are by new users - how about some cotton wool?
- it isn't obvious which link takes you to the new question
- the {community} line seems redundant, just adding confusion?
- it is confusing that two links captioned the same go to different places

How about something more like:

> It has been suggested that your question is more suited to {destination site}; your question has been migrated automatically, and can now be found {here}.
>
> closed as belongs on {...} by {...}

(where {here} is the link to the new question)

Changes:

- it is a bit clearer to new users what has happened and why
- it is easier to see where the new question is - what to click on
- there aren't the "same label, different destination" phenomenon
- just a bit less jarring

Thoughts?

Comment: This is a dupe... can't find it so far. I even think it was denied.

Comment: You mean this one? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16740/migrating-questions-causes-too-much-visual-noise

Comment: Or that one? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11580