# The Rules of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, fun

**Note**: This is intended as a joke post and is not representative of the rules of Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange. For the actual rules of the site, please see the [tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) or the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help).

---

I felt like expanding the first rule Jeff posted on the [blog a while back.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/). They are all based on the original Fight Club rules.

**The Rules of Stack Overflow.**

- **1st RULE:** You do not talk about Stack Overflow on Stack Overflow
- **2nd RULE:** You DO NOT talk about Stack Overflow on Stack Overflow. That's what Meta is for.
- **3rd RULE:** If someone votes to close or reports to the mod, the question is over.
- **4th RULE:** Only one accepted answer to a question.
- **5th RULE:** One answer from a user at a time.
- **6th RULE:** No shirts, no shoes.
- **7th RULE:** Questions will go on as long as they have to.
- **8th RULE:** If this is your first time at Stack Overflow, you HAVE to read the FAQ.
- **9th RULE:** Paint whenever you can.
- **10th RULE:** Don't use soul-less circles!
- **11th RULE:** NEVER EVER make up rules for Stack Overflow!

Comment: @John the original 8 rules are straight from Fight Club, just changed to fit SO.

Comment: @Ólafur: I'm stretching the rules ;)

Comment: man that's a lot of downvotes. *why do you people hate fun so much??*

Comment: They just hate volcanoes and vikings!

Comment: I like vikings! Especially when they laugh! (And I upvoted)

Comment: `Rule 11: NEVER EVER make up rules for Stack Overflow!` is a self-destructive rule!

Comment: @o.k.w: Surprised?

Comment: @John: After all these, not really :P

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruces_sketch

Comment: I like vikings.  They taste like chicken.

Comment: I don't understand.  The 6th rule should be "No pants," because we *are* all on computers, after all...

Comment: About rule 6....my cubicle is next to the window, and this is Minnesota.  In the winter, it gets cold in here, and wearing neither shoes nor shirt would be uncomfortable.

Comment: Might be nice if the mention of the FAQ was a link ;)

Comment: This brings back memories of when I was younger and stupider.

Comment: Is their any list of site enforced rules? Like one cannot comment unless having some n reputations. One cannot edit unless having m reputations. And more complicated once like revert downvotes if someone downvoted same person straight on 3 different places? Is their one place documentation for this?

Answer (score 6):

7th RULE: [Questions will go on as long as they have to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon).

Comment: +1 for providing such a great example of this :)

Answer (score 3):

How about no [soul-less circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-do-i-post-a-screenshot-on-stack-overflow/28529#28529) on SO and Meta? :P

Comment: *No soul-less circle __nor high quality compression jpg__ on Meta?*

Comment: @voyager: Is `png` preferred then?

Comment: @o.k.w: Read the comments: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16740/migrating-questions-causes-too-much-visual-noise

Answer (score 3):

We're missing "[don't be a jerk](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)."

Of course, this list is all in good fun, so maybe the one real rule should be left off of it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Rule 12: Animals automatically beat out humans. This goes for ponies, cats and lizards, but not dogs because they drool.

Comment: Rule 12.1: This does not apply to Jon Skeet because he's not really a human.

Answer (score 2):

Rule 12 (or maybe 11, and move 11 to 12): [Clear your cache](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31687/bug-during-upvote).

Answer (score -1):

If the 4th rule is true, then why does the system allow the selection of more than one answer?

Comment: what gave you the idea you could select more than one answer?

Comment: There can only be one accepted answer.

Comment: @Olafur:  Too many words in your comment.  Just, "There can be only one."